# Fill adjacent columns using conditional in Python

Tags: python

There is a data cleaning task I usually do in Excel but now I need to do it in Python and I'm really struggling with it.
In the following table, I use IF and AND functions in Desc2 and Desc3 variables, to identify situations where column Level has a value of 3 followed by 2, then I fullfill it as shown in the table 2.

For example, to put 'FUT CAMP ESPANHOL VT' in the Desc2 i would do "=IF(AND(G3='2',G4='3'),A2,'n.a.')".

[image: Raw Data]

[image]

Is there a way to do it in Python? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: would be much helpful to see your `input data` and `the code you wrote`

Comment: Your question is lacking a few things: it's not clear how the second table follows from the first (since you're not sharing your Excel code), but more importantly, you haven't tried doing it in Python (or aren't sharing any of your code), so there's no way to help you other than doing all the work for you. As for your question: yes, I'm sure you can do it in Python, there's literally nothing Excel can do that Python couldn't do - whether Python is the best way of doing it depends on circumstances. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried something with numpy.where clauses but didn't work. I'm gonna try something with iloc later on.